# Calculate the greatest difference in a nested list

Tags: python, nested-lists, textblob

I created a list with lists from a text document with WordBlob. Now I want to create a list with the greatest difference within each list and I am only interested in the polarity. I thought of appending the highest and lowest numbers to another list and then substracting them from each other. But how can I refer to the numbers in 'polarity' at all? This is my nested list:

```py
[[Sentiment(polarity=0.35, subjectivity=0.65),
  Sentiment(polarity=0.0, subjectivity=0.0),
  Sentiment(polarity=0.0, subjectivity=0.0),
  Sentiment(polarity=0.6, subjectivity=0.87),
  Sentiment(polarity=0.0, subjectivity=0.0),
  Sentiment(polarity=0.0, subjectivity=0.0)],
 [Sentiment(polarity=0.0, subjectivity=0.0),
  Sentiment(polarity=0.5, subjectivity=0.8),
  Sentiment(polarity=0.0, subjectivity=0.0),
  Sentiment(polarity=-0.29, subjectivity=0.54),
  Sentiment(polarity=0.0, subjectivity=0.0),
  Sentiment(polarity=0.25, subjectivity=1.0)],
  [Sentiment(polarity=0.5, subjectivity=0.8),
  Sentiment(polarity=0.0, subjectivity=0.0)]]
```

Does someone has an idea? Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the python builtin functions `min` and `max` together with their `key` parameter to find the smallest/biggest value in a list, given the key criterion. Written as a function, it could look like this:

```py
def polarity_diffs(sentiments):
    diffs = []
    for row in sentiments:
        smallest = min(row, key=lambda s: s.polarity).polarity
        biggest = max(row, key=lambda s: s.polarity).polarity
        diffs.append(biggest - smallest)
    return diffs
```

Given a dummy object and some test data -

```py
class Sentiment:  # Example class
    def __init__(self, polarity, subjectivity):
        self.polarity = polarity
        self.subjectivity = subjectivity

test_data = [
    # normal values
    [Sentiment(polarity=0.35, subjectivity=0.65),
     Sentiment(polarity=0.0, subjectivity=0.0),
     Sentiment(polarity=0.0, subjectivity=0.0),
     Sentiment(polarity=0.6, subjectivity=0.87),
     Sentiment(polarity=0.0, subjectivity=0.0),
     Sentiment(polarity=0.0, subjectivity=0.0)],
    # more normal values
    [Sentiment(polarity=0.0, subjectivity=0.0),
     Sentiment(polarity=0.5, subjectivity=0.8),
     Sentiment(polarity=0.0, subjectivity=0.0),
     Sentiment(polarity=-0.29, subjectivity=0.54),
     Sentiment(polarity=0.0, subjectivity=0.0),
     Sentiment(polarity=0.25, subjectivity=1.0)],
    # only a single entry
    [Sentiment(polarity=0.35, subjectivity=0.65)],
    # multiple entries, but identical
    [Sentiment(polarity=0.0, subjectivity=0.0),
     Sentiment(polarity=0.0, subjectivity=0.0)]
]
```

- these are the results:

```py
for diff in polarity_diffs(x):
    print(diff)
0.6   # normal values
0.79  # more normal values
0.0   # only a single entry
0.0   # multiple entries, but identical
```

Comment: This is a solution for my problem - thanks! But it also appends a number, if there is just one number. I want the difference between the numbers. Do you have an idea?

Comment: do you mean that you want to skip sub-lists that only have one element, or skip if the difference is `0`?

Comment: I want a list with one entry for each sublist. If there is just one number in a sublist, a zero should be added in the final list. If the difference is zero, then it is zero in the final list, too.

Comment: In cases like that, it helps if you offer test data and expected output in your main question. It can be tricky to understand corner cases like these from words.

Comment: Huh, it already works like that if I try it with a single-entry list.

Answer (score 1):

Given an example class that's how you access the desired element in your case:

```
class Sentiment:  # Example class
    def __init__(self, polarity, subjectivity):
        self.polarity = polarity
        self.subjectivity = subjectivity


ar = [[Sentiment(polarity=0.35, subjectivity=0.65),
      Sentiment(polarity=0.0, subjectivity=0.0),
      Sentiment(polarity=0.0, subjectivity=0.0),
      Sentiment(polarity=0.6, subjectivity=0.87),
      Sentiment(polarity=0.0, subjectivity=0.0),
      Sentiment(polarity=0.0, subjectivity=0.0)],
     [Sentiment(polarity=0.0, subjectivity=0.0),
      Sentiment(polarity=0.5, subjectivity=0.8),
      Sentiment(polarity=0.0, subjectivity=0.0),
      Sentiment(polarity=-0.29, subjectivity=0.54),
      Sentiment(polarity=0.0, subjectivity=0.0),
      Sentiment(polarity=0.25, subjectivity=1.0)]]

print(ar[0][0].polarity)  # this is the first polarity value
```